# addEntriesFromDictionary: a true copy method?

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to understand exactly what is going on with this method, as noted in the Apple docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html

If I create an `NSMutableDicationary` and use `addEntriesFromDictionary:` to fill it, can I do anything I want to this mutable dictionary without affecting the original immutable dictionary from where these items came?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original dictionary will not be modified. *However*, if the keys or values of the original dictionary are themselves mutable in some way (e.g. they're instances of `UIView` or `NSMutableArray`) and you modify them, the changes will be reflected in the original dictionary.

To avoid that, make a deep copy of the original dictionary before adding it to the new dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *deepCopy = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary: original copyItems: YES];
if (deepCopy) {
    [destination addEntriesFromDictionary: deepCopy];
    [deepCopy release];
}
```

Comment: I know. I was keeping it simple.

Comment: these seems quite efficient. i am reading Jeff LaMarche's iphone development book, and he creates quite a long and verbose category method that would appear to do what yours is doing here. in fact, here is what he suggests:

Comment: `- (NSMutableDictionary *) mutableDeepCopy {

NSMutableDictionary *returnDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
initWithCapacity:[self count]]; NSArray *keys = [self allKeys];
for (id key in keys) {
id oneValue = [self valueForKey:key]; id oneCopy = nil;
if ([oneValue respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableDeepCopy)]) oneCopy = [oneValue mutableDeepCopy];
else if ([oneValue respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopy)]) oneCopy = [oneValue mutableCopy];
if (oneCopy == nil)
oneCopy = [oneValue copy];
[returnDict setValue:oneCopy forKey:key];
[oneCopy release]; }
return returnDict; }`

Comment: i'm wondering why such code would be necessary if a simple `deepCopy` would do the trick as you provided?

Comment: There is no `-deepCopy` method in the stock libraries; he's basically implementing an analogue to `NSCopying` that does deep copying.

Comment: why is such an analogue necessary if short code like your suggestion works easily?

Comment: Because it removes code repetition by allowing arbitrary classes to implement the hypothetical `DeepCopying` protocol, so you can just go `[myObject deepCopy]` and have a deep copy. Take a look at the `NSCopying` protocol for info on why *that* exists.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, modifications you make to the new dictionary will not affect the old one.  Any changes you make to the objects *inside* the dictionary will affect those inside the original dictionary, though.  They are the same same objects, after all.  As the documentation says:

> Each value object from *otherDictionary* is sent a **`retain`** message before being added to the receiving dictionary. In contrast, each key object is copied ... and the copy is added to the receiving dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

You can check for yourself by logging the addresses of the keys and values. My guess is that it copies the keys, as is the standard `NSDictionary` behavior, and simply retains the values. You can mutate the *dictionary* (which comprises just the key->value mappings) all you want, but if you mutate the objects that are its *values*, you'll be mutating those objects everywhere.

**EDIT**: Logging a test case as suggested indeed shows that is the behavior. The copied key will in fact be the same as the original key for the common case of an immutable string key.