# JSON data, the way to edit it

Tags: ios, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

I need to get json array and add an element to it and than send it back. My question is how can I edit json array elements? The only way I can find:

```
[firstElm addEntriesFromDictionary:[[forTheDopOp objectForKey:@"blablabla"] objectAtIndex:1]];
    NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:DateAndTime forKey:@"value"];
    [firstElm addEntriesFromDictionary:dic];
    [order addObject:firstElm];
    [secondElm addEntriesFromDictionary:[[forTheDopOp objectForKey:@"blablabla"] objectAtIndex:2]];
    NSDictionary * dic1 = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:backDateAndTime forKey:@"value"];
    [secondElm addEntriesFromDictionary:dic1];
    [orderOpSender addObject:secondElm];
```

but it doesn't work if I need to do it in a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < [[[[forTheDopOp objectForKey:@"blablabla"] objectAtIndex:3] objectForKey:@"option_value"] count]; i++) {
        [valuesElm addEntriesFromDictionary:[[[[forTheDopOp objectForKey:@"blablabla"] objectAtIndex:3] objectForKey:@"blablabla"] objectAtIndex:i]];
        NSDictionary * dic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[[[[[forTheDopOp objectForKey:@"blablabla"] objectAtIndex:3] objectForKey:@"blablabla"] objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"value"];
        [valuesElm addEntriesFromDictionary:dic];
        [orderOp addObject:valuesElm];
    }
```

In the end I'm getting an array of same elements.

example of my json:

```
{ "product_id": 83, "firstname":"111", "lastname": "222", "email": "e2e2e@wsdwsd.ru", "telephone":"089234","options":[
{
"name":"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u043f\u043e\u043b\u0443\u0447\u0435\u043d\u0438\u044f",
"type":"datetime",
"option_value":"",
"required":"1",
"value": "2014-09-01 9:10",
"product_option_id":"263",
"option_id":"15"
},
    {
"name":"\u0414\u0430\u0442\u0430 \u0432\u043e\u0437\u0432\u0440\u0430\u0442\u0430",
"type":"datetime",
"option_value":"",
"required":"1",
"product_option_id":"264",
"value": "2014-10-01 10:10",
"option_id":"16"
}
```

Can I add string to the options immediately?

Comment: Parse the JSON into NSArrays/NSDictionarys, update as needed, then serialize back to JSON.  Be sure to specify the "mutable containers" option when parsing.

Comment: As stated it's impossible to tell what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to edit your values, you should use NSMutableDictionary

Comment: can you give me an example firstElm and secondElm is a NSMutableDictionary

Comment: i'm not sure i understand your problem. maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6931104/addentriesfromdictionary-a-true-copy-method

Comment: Specify the "mutable containers" option when parsing with NSJSONSerialization.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
NSMutableArray *newForTheDopOp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for(NSDictionary *option in forTheDopOp[@"options"])){
   NSLog(@"option = %@", option);
   NSMutableDictionary *newOption = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
   [newOption addEntriesFromDictionary:option];
   [newOption setObject:@"test" forKey:@"option_value"];
   [newForTheDopOp addObject:newOption];
   NSLog(@"newOption = %@", newOption);
}
NSLog(@"newForTheDopOp = %@", newForTheDopOp);
```

Comment: this will append a pairvalue with `somekey` as a key, then add the modified data to an `NSMutableArray` called `jsonModifiedOptions`

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Comment: @lhawks its needs to be a mutable array  like in my code `NSMutableDictionary *data` you cannot change an `NSArray`

Comment: `NSMutableArray *jsonModifiedOptions =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSMutableDictionary *data in [[[forTheDopOp objectForKey:@"options"] objectAtIndex:3] objectForKey:@"option_value"]) {
            [data setObject:@"test" forKey:@"value"];
            [jsonModifiedOptions addObject:data];
        }`

Comment: But your code is different you are accessing `[[[forTheDopOp objectForKey:@"options"] objectAtIndex:3] objectForKey:@"option_value"]` @lhawks

Comment: @lhawks maybe you meant `for (NSMutableDictionary *data in forTheDopOp[@"options"])`

Comment: I need to add value not to options, but to option_value. Am I need to implement more NSMutableDictionary like : `for (NSMutableDictionary *data in jsonDict[@"options"]) { for (NSMutableDictionary *data1 in data[@"option_value"]) {` ?

Comment: @lhawks my answer remains the same, in the loop you change to `[data setObject:someObject forKey:@"option_value"];` check my edit

Comment: the same problem with this code `NSMutableArray *jsonModifiedOptions =  [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (NSMutableDictionary *data in forTheDopOp[@"options"]) {
            [data setObject:@"test" forKey:@"option_value"];
            [jsonModifiedOptions addObject:data];
        }`

Comment: @lhawks ok at this point im going to have to test it myself, I get back to you shortly

Comment: hello, did you test this or not yet? I'm still waiting for your response, thx

Comment: @lhawks Im so sorry I took to long to get back to you, I could not find your question under the objective C tag. I have updated the answer with the solution